# App crashes without any message. In device

Tags: android

I have a problem running my app on a device.

Not on all devices!

On many devices(Lenovo android 4.2.2, Lenovo 4.4, Nexus 4 android 4.4 and more) it's running perfectly!

Unfortunately on some devices, such Samsung with android 4.4(upgrade to 5.0), Wiko android 4.4.4 app crashes without any message.

When I click on the app icon, the app opens then it shows a white screen for less than 1 second before the app closes.

I've made a apk file like this: In Android Studio I press "run" triangle, after it finished building I copy apk from "appname\app\build\outputs\apk". app-debug.apk

Does anyone have the same problem ?

Thanks for any helpful information !

Important:

The device is for 2,500 kilometers from me

**UPD:**
I try to launch "empty" app and it works!

Comment: of course it won't display an error msg because its a situation that you didn't handle plus you are running apk!
first go to your IDE and the project as it is on Samsung with android 4.4(upgrade to 5.0) then come back with the logCat!!!!!!!!

Comment: check your logcat for error messages

Comment: Try creating sign version of your app [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: Guys, of course I can debug app with Android Studio if device not be far from 2.500km from me!

Comment: What are you doing on start up? I guess you are loading some resources.. locally or over the internet? What does your manifest look like? I'm shooting at the dark but you've given almost no information...

Comment: You could add ACRA crash reporting to your app (acra.ch) and set it up to send emails with crash reports to you when the app crashes. You'll need to make a new APK with the new feature in it though.

Comment: @KirilAleksandrov, yep I load xml file from server. And try to launch "empty app" - it's work, app launchs..